# Boto3 ignores AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI

Tags: boto3, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs

I'm in an ECS Task and want to use certain AWS services. I have attached the appropriate role to the task and the environment variable `AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI` is visible. When I query it manually and setup the credentials as environment variables (id, key, token, region) I can work with the AWS API.

I assumed that boto3 is able to handle authentication transparently? But when I do the following

`client = boto3.client('ecs')`

I get an error that the region is required. And when I add the region via env the request fails because the token is invalid.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I got it to work. Instead of `boto3.client('ecs')` I have to create a session first and then use it to get the client:

```py
import boto3
session = boto3.session.Session()
print(session.get_credentials().get_frozen_credentials())
ecs_client = session.client("ecs")
```

Like that the script will work running within an ECS task.

Comment: https://github.com/signal-ai/prometheus-ecs-sd/issues/10